# D&D5 Character throw distance

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, throwing-things

In my campaign, there is one player that play a **Goliath Runic Knight**, and has a **20 in Strength**. Having the possibilty to get a **size bigger with Gigantism**, and counting another size bigger that he really is for pushing, draging and lifting things with **Powerful Build**.

Rules tells he can possibly lift something that weight around **900kg/2000lbs** *(or 1200kg/2600lbs, not 100% sure about the math on this one*), and with this power house of a man, i'm 100% sure that the question "how far can i throw this character/monster/object/Hot-dog stand" is going to pop up.

The problem is, i don't have an answer for that, for specific object, like weapons or throwable, it's usually written in the rules, but i find nothing on throwing the party's dwarf, so i require a bit of help there.

Also, does anyone know if there is a chart or something for damage taken if this man throw a creature on, say a tree (or a tree on a creature), or i will just have to guess ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101484/35026) answer your question? There is not much detail about strength affecting your throwing distance but the linked answer and the other answers of that question should give some indications on how to rule throwing improvised weapons or party members.