# Could a Dragon use an unconscious PC as a thrown weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, unconscious, throwing-things

I like to ground my games with a cinematic scope and my players may come up against a dragon pretty soon. The dragons are very much feral and evil and so I am looking to show their feral nature.

If a player was knocked to making death saving throws, could the dragon (using D&D 5e Mechanics) pick up the player and use them as some form of improvised thrown weapon, and throw their barely living body at another PC?

An Improvised Weapon would require the person to be dead and thus classed as an object (RAW) but is there anything else that would stop me from doing this in the books? It's a cool moment but I don't want to do something unfair.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange. It's great to see a creative question and you're surely excited to get some responses but please remember that it's common courtesy here to wait around a day before accepting an answer. This helps us as answerers so that more thorough information can be sourced for an answer. Accepting an answer early can discourage other answers that may be more complete. But thank you for your question and again, welcome!

Comment: @JBH Friendly reminder that answers, even partial answers and/or frame challenges, belong in answers rather than in comments.

Comment: Of course! :-) :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Certainly

First of all, when you say **it's a cool moment** and you are the DM trying to design a compelling encounter, that is all you need. If it is cool, do it. The monsters don't have to play by the same rules as the PCs, and can typically be more compelling without those limitations.

When looking at the rules as written, even [PCs can throw their party members](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101451/41726). A dead goblin is specifically listed as an option for improvised weapons:

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a **dead goblin**.

The [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons) clarify that:

> An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

...meaning a dragon can certainly throw a dead or dying PC and would use the improvised weapon rules to do so.

Comment: Do you think that doing so would likely cause damage to the unconscious PC and a failed death save?

Comment: _"The monsters don't have to play by the same rules as the PCs..."_ Right up until the PCs polymorph into monsters. If you give an ability to monsters, be prepared for the PCs to use that same ability if they change into the same monster.

Comment: If you're big enough and strong enough to physically throw an enemy *and* you've succeeded on a grapple, I'd certainly allow it at my table. For example, if you're normal human-scale PCs fighting sprites -- or rats -- and you've managed to grab one, I'd let you throw it as an improvised weapon, dealing half damage each to the target and the projectile. (Or you can throw them against a solid object for full damage to the projectile.) I mean, as as on-the-fly ruling that seems totally fine to me.

Comment: @NautArch Newton's Third Law certainly implies that.

Comment: @NautArch I personally would think so.  How often do you hear: "don't move a seriously injured person unless you are a medical professional".  I think being picked up and thrown into somebody would be worse than just being moved.  Being thrown and not hitting somebody would probably be even worse

Comment: Seems like there's no reason to limit it to just "dead or dying" or even paralyzed or otherwise incapacitated PCs .  If the dragon can successfully pick you up, they should be able to throw you regardless of your condition.  Being conscious and mobile would obviously give you a chance to struggle and possibly escape, but it wouldn't necessarily prevent a sufficiently strong enemy from throwing you anyhow.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It would be much harder to throw an unwilling creature--they could grab onto whatever is gripping them.  If you can't fully control the creature you picked up you have no hope of hitting your target and might not even be able to throw it at all.  For mechanical purposes (but not for magical purposes) I would consider an incapacitated creature an object, though.

Comment: @NautArch The basic idea is to throw the player at another one and ask for a Dex Save or Str Save (DC set to the dragons spellcasting save). Dex to dodge (player loses 2) and Str to catch the player (losing none). On a fail the other PC will take like 1d8 damage and be knocked prone.

They are only level 5 so the idea is not to kill them but to scare them and get the gears rolling. I have no clerics or any way to revive the player so will make for an interesting side quest if someone meets a terrible fate.

Comment: @ItsScottish Not damaging the thrown PC doesn’t make a ton of sense, and damaging them would result in death save(s).

Comment: @NautArch Cuz im not out here trying to kill them. I am trying to place the unconcious player right next to the healer. Nobody in their right mind is going to run up to a dragon, heal their teammate and walk away. I want to make space for the dragon (and it's rider) to escape. My only healers are paladins and they are level 5. Revivify aint an option yet and given its Dragonlance, if the PCs dont have it I gotta look for Fizban

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it could.

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon Attack, you can use an Unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head--butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons). On a hit, an Unarmed strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your modifier. You are proficient with your Unarmed strikes.

I'd certainly say that throwing someone counts as a *"similar forceful blow"*. This wouldn't be an effective strategy due to the very low damage, and the DM (you) would need to decide how exactly would the dragon roll against two PCs (one thrown, one being thrown at). You would also need to consider the fact that the attack against the unconscious character, if it hits and the attacker is within 5 feet, is an automatic critical hit, and a critical hit equals two failed death saving throws. Thus, by doing what you described, you may kill your PC without giving his comrades a chance to heal him.

**Personally** as a DM I would rule that being grabbed by a dragon is not yet an attack, so no crit and no double death fail for a thrown character. If the dragon succeeds against the AC of the character he is throwing the body at, I would count both to be hit. If not, I'd rule that the character being thrown just tumbled relatively harmlessly. I'd rule that way because the player whose character is down probably is having a bad day now anyway, and finishing his character off wouldn't add "cinematic scope", just frustration.

Comment: "If not, I'd rule that the character being thrown just tumbled relatively harmlessly." I disagree.  I actually think quite the opposite.  Getting thrown into another person is not going to hurt as bad as the dragon missing and you hitting a wall or the ground

Comment: Unarmed Strike rules are for melee attacks, not ranged.

Comment: @Feathercrown i'm not aware of any rule directly stating that. Can you point me to the source? Sure, that's how they are used almost all of the time, but that proves nothing.

Comment: @Kevin that's sensible point of view. On the other hand, tumbling on soft grass would be less hurtful than hitting armored paladin. A lots of things we can't know, to make the best ruling possible.

Comment: @Mołot It's in the quote in your post: "Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon Attack, you can use an Unarmed strike"

Comment: IOW, yes you can do this, and yes its a cool visual. However, realistically this will almost certianly kill the unconscious PC, and a DM normally **should not do that lightly**. I'd definitely consider "because its a cool visual" to be "doing that lightly", and I'd imagine your players would too. Perhaps consider instead flavoring the flinging of the PC as part of the attack damage that knocked them out.

Comment: @Feathercrown fair point, your reading is more strict than mine, but makes sense. Anyway, at most tables rules are there to serve the narrative, not the other way around.

Comment: @T.E.D. Please notice that I warned against inflicting unavoidable death save failures and killing off pc in my answer.

Comment: Totally noticed that. Was just a bit worried that the answer did so in a diplomatic enough manner that a person exited about their desired course of action may not have gotten the message as fully as they should. So I added a comment to emphasize the point.

Comment: While it is an automatic critical that's assuming the dragon intends to do damage.  I have no problem with a dragon contemptuously throwing an unconscious PC at the party--no damage from picking them up and the dragon doesn't have to use it's full strength for the throw, either--falling damage from the throw and nothing more.

Comment: Hey @Mołot  - I would be treating it as once unconcious, the dragon could easily pick the person up without rolling an attack or check. The throw would have the possibility to damage the player being thrown and the person its being thrown at. -- I intend to throw the player at the paladin (lay on hands & Cure wounds) and cheese it outta there. The dragon is a scare tactic, it's just in the module. I don't want to kill them and thats why im planning ahead here. The dragon is feral, if a player does down infront of it, instictivly it would kill them. "Discarding" them avoids that